# AttributeError: 'property' object has no attribute '__name__'

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, data-science

While I am importing the pandas in my data science project I am getting such kind of error. Does anyone know what might cause this?

I tried with re-installation of pandas and python also
I also tried with wheel

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

AttributeError                           
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-b231533e2331> in <module>
      1 import numpy as np
----> 2 import pandas as pd
      3 from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
      4 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
      5 from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

AttributeError: 'property' object has no attribute '__name__'
```

Comment: Please format the question properly with code and error details. It is not understandable right now.

Answer (score -1):

"I got the solution for same. It may be multiple python version installation problem in same system problem so you need to create a virtual environment for your data science project now steps for creating virtual environment...."

`1. install python 3.x`
`2. install pip`
`3. pip install virtualenv #for creating virtual environment`
`4. mkvirtualenv folder_name #command for creating virtual environment`
`5 pip install pandas # run this command in virtual environment directory`

now import pandas it will work fine.