# Matplotlib returning: AttributeError: 'property' object has no attribute '__name__'

Tags: python, matplotlib, web-scraping, attributes, word-cloud

I've built a webscraper in python (Jupyter) to pull post content from a blog and I would like to use the csv file to create a wordcloud. This is the wordcloud code I am using:

```
%matplotlib notebook
from os import path
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS

# Open and read blog_stuff csv file
file = open("blog_stuff.csv",'r')
text = file.read()
file.close()

# Generate WordCloud 
# !!!make sure the path for the font is correct!!!
wordcloud = WordCloud(font_path='C:/Windows/Fonts/Calibri.ttf', relative_scaling = 0.25 ).generate(text)

# Save image
plt.savefig('wordcloud.png')

# Display Image
plt.show()
```

I keep running into an attribute error on all of the tutorials I follow. This is the error:

> AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in  ----> 1
>   get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'notebook') 2 from os
>   import path 3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 4 import random 5
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py in
>   run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line, _stack_depth) 2305
>   kwargs['local_ns'] = sys._getframe(stack_depth).f_locals 2306 with
>   self.builtin_trap: -> 2307 result = fn(args, *kwargs) 2308 return
>   result 2309
>
> in matplotlib(self, line)
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magic.py in (f, a,
>   *k) 185 # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state. 186 def magic_deco(arg): --> 187 call = lambda f, a, *k: f(a, *k) 188 189 if
>   callable(arg):
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magics\pylab.py in
>   matplotlib(self, line) 97 print("Available matplotlib backends: %s" %
>   backends_list) 98 else: ---> 99 gui, backend =
>   self.shell.enable_matplotlib(args.gui) 100
>   self._show_matplotlib_backend(args.gui, backend) 101
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py in
>   enable_matplotlib(self, gui) 3382 gui, backend =
>   pt.find_gui_and_backend(self.pylab_gui_select) 3383 -> 3384
>   pt.activate_matplotlib(backend) 3385 pt.configure_inline_support(self,
>   backend) 3386
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py in
>   activate_matplotlib(backend) 311 matplotlib.rcParams['backend'] =
>   backend 312 --> 313 import matplotlib.pyplot 314
>   matplotlib.pyplot.switch_backend(backend) 315
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in  30 from
>   cycler import cycler 31 import matplotlib ---> 32 import
>   matplotlib.colorbar 33 import matplotlib.image 34 from matplotlib
>   import rcsetup, style
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colorbar.py in  25 26
>   import matplotlib as mpl ---> 27 import matplotlib.artist as martist
>   28 import matplotlib.cbook as cbook 29 import matplotlib.collections
>   as collections
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in  55 56
>   ---> 57 class Artist(object): 58 """ 59 Abstract base class for objects that render into a FigureCanvas.
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in Artist() 62 """
>   63 @cbook.deprecated("3.1") ---> 64 @property 65 def aname(self): 66
>   return 'Artist'
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\deprecation.py in
>   deprecate(obj, message, name, alternative, pending, addendum) 180 pass
>   181 """ --> 182 183 def deprecate(obj, message=message, name=name,
>   alternative=alternative, 184 pending=pending, obj_type=obj_type,
>   addendum=addendum):
>
> AttributeError: 'property' object has no attribute 'name'

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56235417/attributeerror-property-object-has-no-attribute-name